# FFMPEG Optional Entries in -var_stream_map

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a script that records an x11 display and outputs three HLS streams.

```
./ffmpeg -y \
    -f x11grab -framerate 60 -s 1920x1080 -i :1.0 \
    -c:v:0 libx264 -c:s:0 copy -c:a:0 aac -b:v:0 4000k -b:a:0 512k -s:v:0 1920x1080 -r:0 30 -g:0 90 -preset:0 superfast -tune:0 zerolatency -level:v:0 4 -f flv \
    -c:v:1 libx264 -c:s:1 copy -c:a:1 aac -b:v:1 2500k -b:a:1 256k -s:v:1 1280x720 -r:1 30 -g:1 90 -preset:1 superfast -tune:1 zerolatency -level:v:1 4 -f flv \
    -c:v:2 libx264 -c:s:2 copy -c:a:2 aac -b:v:2 800k -b:a:2 256k -s:v:2 960x540 -r:2 30 -g:2 90 -preset:2 superfast -tune:2 zerolatency -level:v:2 4 -f flv \
    -hls_time 6 \
    -hls_list_size 2 \
    -hls_flags delete_segments \
    -map 0:v -map 0:a? -map 0:s? -map 0:v -map 0:a? -map 0:s? -map 0:v -map 0:a? -map 0:s? \
    -var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1 v:2,a:2" \
    -f hls -master_pl_name "${name}.m3u8" \
    -hls_segment_filename "/tmp/hls/${name}_%v-%d.ts" \
    -max_muxing_queue_size 1024 \
    "/tmp/hls/${name}_%v.m3u8"
```

This line:

```
-map 0:v -map 0:a? -map 0:s? -map 0:v -map 0:a? -map 0:s? -map 0:v -map 0:a? -map 0:s? \
```

Has question marks after each `0:a`, this is because the input does not always have audio, so it ignores the error when there is no audio present, and maps it when there is.

However, the following switch:

```
-var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1 v:2,a:2" \
```

Will only work if there is audio present, is there a way I can have -var_stream_map with entries that will ignore errors like -map does?

Here are the errors if I try to use this current script with no audio:

```
[hls @ 0x6231800] Unable to map stream at a:0
[hls @ 0x6231800] Variant stream info update failed with status ffffffea
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:2 --
```

If it's relevant, here is the entire output:

```
ffmpeg version 4.0.3-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
[x11grab @ 0x6229300] 16 bits per pixel screen is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
[x11grab @ 0x6229300] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #0, x11grab, from ':1.0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1546439595.240575, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (RGB[16] / 0x10424752), rgb565le, 1920x1080, 60 fps, 1000k tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:2 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x62334c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x62334c0] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 4.0, 4:4:4, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x62334c0] 264 - core 157 r2935 545de2f - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x1 me=dia subme=1 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=6 threads=4 lookahead_threads=4 sliced_threads=1 slices=4 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=1 keyint=90 keyint_min=9 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc=abr mbtree=0 bitrate=4000 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[libx264 @ 0x6234840] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x6234840] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 4.0, 4:4:4, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x6234840] 264 - core 157 r2935 545de2f - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x1 me=dia subme=1 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=6 threads=4 lookahead_threads=4 sliced_threads=1 slices=4 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=1 keyint=90 keyint_min=9 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc=abr mbtree=0 bitrate=2500 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[libx264 @ 0x6235740] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x6235740] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 4.0, 4:4:4, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x6235740] 264 - core 157 r2935 545de2f - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x1 me=dia subme=1 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=6 threads=4 lookahead_threads=4 sliced_threads=1 slices=4 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=1 keyint=90 keyint_min=9 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc=abr mbtree=0 bitrate=800 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[hls @ 0x6231800] Unable to map stream at a:0
[hls @ 0x6231800] Variant stream info update failed with status ffffffea
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:2 -- 
[libx264 @ 0x62334c0] frame I:1     Avg QP:31.45  size: 91065
[libx264 @ 0x62334c0] mb I  I16..4: 56.4%  0.0% 43.6%
[libx264 @ 0x62334c0] final ratefactor: 36.79
[libx264 @ 0x62334c0] coded y,u,v intra: 42.4% 8.7% 11.4%
[libx264 @ 0x62334c0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 53% 32% 11%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x62334c0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 28% 20% 14%  8%  6%  6%  6%  5%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x62334c0] kb/s:21855.60
[libx264 @ 0x6234840] frame I:1     Avg QP:30.27  size: 62907
[libx264 @ 0x6234840] mb I  I16..4: 48.6%  0.0% 51.4%
[libx264 @ 0x6234840] final ratefactor: 35.22
[libx264 @ 0x6234840] coded y,u,v intra: 53.9% 14.2% 17.2%
[libx264 @ 0x6234840] i16 v,h,dc,p: 49% 36% 11%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x6234840] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 26% 19% 15%  8%  7%  6%  6%  6%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x6234840] kb/s:15097.68
[libx264 @ 0x6235740] final ratefactor: 29.77
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: `var_stream_map` does not support optional entries.

Comment: @Gyan In order to use var_stream_map, should I first check if the video contains audio? Without audio, this is an error. `-var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1 v:2,a:2"`

Comment: Yes, that is right.